# Creating pages within tabs with Javascript - Link not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tabs

I have an HTML with tabs, based on this example:

http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery

What I'm trying to do is to create sub-pages within each tab. An arrow at the bottom of the tab text links you to more text, within that current tab's div.

It works in HTML, but when I try to create the same element using Javascript it doesn't. Then the link simply doesn't work.

You can see what I mean here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpPREB

The Javascript I'm using is

```
function createArrow () {
var ap = document.createElement("ul");
  ap.className = "tab-links";
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  var aText = document.createTextNode("> new arrow to tab 1, pg 2");
  a.appendChild(aText)
  a.title = "Next";
  a.href = "#tab-1-pg-2";
  ap.appendChild(a);
  document.getElementById("tab-1").appendChild(ap);                
}
```

Any ideas on why the link doesn't work, even though it is the same as the link created directly in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question ... try changing your click event handler to be delegated.

`jQuery('.tabs').on('click', ' .tab-links a', function(e) {`

The `.tab-links` don't exist when you originally bound the event handler, so you need to delegate it to the parent `.tabs`
Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events